# An exception occurred .. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlexception, unhandled-exception

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connect_str = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Chamod\Documents\Chamod.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        string ms_sql_str = "SELECT * FROM Table ";
        cmd.CommandText = ms_sql_str;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connect_str);
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if(dr.HasRows)
        {
            Session["Admin"] = t1.Text.Trim();
            Response.Redirect("First.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
          //  spnmsg.Visible = true;
        }
        connection.Close();

    }
}
```

I am creating a login system for a hotel. When I'm going to login to system,
VS 2015 is pointing to `SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();` row.
It is saying that

> "An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request."

I had lot's of errors and I don't know how to finish the code. Please give me a solution.

Comment: Hi. It would be great if you also vote for an answer when you accept it. You can click up arrow near the answer to upvote. It's recommended and reasonable. More information stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TABLE` is a [reserved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql) keyword  so you should change it's name or you should enclose it in square brackets like `[Table]`:

```
string ms_sql_str = "SELECT * FROM [Table] ";
```

However in MySQL I think you should use back-ticks (``` `` ```):

```
string ms_sql_str = "SELECT * FROM `Table` ";
```